# How to setup configuration files environments?

Tags: scala, akka

I have the following environments:

1. dev
2. stage
3. prod

Each environment will have different configuration and in akka documentation it says, that it is possible to [include files](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/configuration.html#including-files).

> **Including files**
>   Sometimes it can be useful to include another
>   configuration file, for example if you have one application.conf with
>   all environment independent settings and then override some settings
>   for specific environments.
>
> Specifying system property with `-Dconfig.resource=/dev.conf` will load
>   the `dev.conf` file, which includes the `application.conf`
>
> ```
> include "application"
>
> akka {   loglevel = "DEBUG" }
> ```

My project environment looks as the following: 
[image]

When I do unit test, I would like to use `dev.conf` configuration file and I have to setup somehow, that it will take the `dev.conf` file.

As the doc says above:

> Specifying system property with `-Dconfig.resource=/dev.conf`

It is not clear to me, how to do it. Where do I have to pass it?

The content of my dev.conf looks as the following:

```
include "application"

akka {loglevel = "DEBUG"}
```

The question is, how to make sure, when the unit test is started, that the `dev.conf` file is going use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a parameter for the JVM. The `-D` option is used to pass key-value system properties.

I see you're using IntelliJ, so I assume you're running your tests directly in there. If that's the case, you can pass parameters to the JVM selecting: `Run -> Edit Configurations... -> (Select your test) -> VM parameters`. Just paste `-Dconfig.resource=/dev.conf` in there, save and run your test.

Comment: Do I have to manually load with `val system = ActorSystem("MySystem", ConfigFactory.load(customConf))` or it will load automatically?

Comment: Yes, you need to load the configuration to use it. The `-Dproperty` is only used to tell which configuration file to use.